# For a Common Lisp library made of multiple packages, is there a standard way to export the API?

Tags: common-lisp

Obviously, the externally visible API is published by exporting symbols. But... what if I have multiple packages (say A, B and C) and A's exported symbols are not all meant to be part of the external API - some of them are needed for B and C? (similarly, B exports some symbols for A and C and some for the external API; C is the 'toplevel' package and all its exported symbols are part of the public API; I want to keep things modular and allow A to hide its innards from B and C, so I avoid '::').

My solution right now is to re-export everything that is meant to be public from C and document that the public API consists only of C's exported symbols and people should stay away from public symbols of A and B under pain of bugs and code broken in the future when internal interfaces change.

Is there a better way?

UPDATE: This is my implementation of my understanding of Xach's answer:

First, let me complete my example. I want to export symbols `symbol-a-1` and `symbol-a-2` from package `a`, symbols `symbol-b-1` and `symbol-b-2` from package `b` and symbols `api-symbol-1` and `api-symbol-2` from package `c`. Only the symbols exported from `c` are part of the public API.

First, the definition for `a`:

```
(defpackage #:a
  (:use #:cl))
```

Note that there aren't any exported symbols :-)

A helper macro (uses Alexandria):

```
(defmacro privately-export (package-name &body symbols)
  `(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
     (defun ,(alexandria:format-symbol *package*
                                       "IMPORT-FROM-~a"
                                       (symbol-name package-name)) ()
       (list :import-from
             ,package-name
             ,@(mapcar (lambda (to-intern)
                         `',(intern (symbol-name to-intern) package-name))
                       symbols)))))
```

Use the macro to 'export privately' :-) :

```
(privately-export :a :symbol-a-1 :symbol-a-2)
```

Now the definition of `b`:

```
(defpackage #:b
  (:use #:cl)
  #.(import-from-a))
```

... `b`'s 'exports':

```
(privately-export :b :symbol-b-1 :symbol-b-2)
```

... `c`'s definition:

```
(defpackage #:c
  (:use #:cl)
  #.(import-from-a)
  #.(import-from-b)
  (:export :api-symbol-1 :api-symbol-2)
```

Problems with this approach:

- `a` cannot use symbols from `b` (without `import`ing symbols from `b` from `a` after both have been defined);
- the syntax `package:symbol` is basically not usable for symbols exported 'privately' (it's either just `symbol` or `package::symbol`).

Comment: Hmmm. Three great answers, rather hard to pick THE answer. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If A and B are primarily for the implementation of C, you can have C's defpackage form drive things with selective use of `:import-from`, since you can import things that aren't external. Then you can selectively re-export from there.

Comment: I missed the fact that `:import-from` can be used with non external symbols. However, updating my code to use `:import-from` instead of `:use` means I'll have to duplicate the `:export` list for the imported package in every 'importer' package. Am I missing something? Any suggestions about transforming `:use`d packages into `:import-from` packages with the lists of symbols for `:import-from` factored out? Thanks!

Comment: I updated the question with an implementation of my understanding of your answer, I'd love to hear about improvements or corrections. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You could add a third package, D, that exports all public API symbols, and consider the A, B and C packages private.  You could then qualify all definitions of functions and variables in the API package using qualified names like in

`(defun D:blah () ...)`

to make it easy to visually spot the definitions of public entry points.

Comment: That's basically what I do now, my C is your D. The suggestion to qualify the definitions of public symbols is food for thought. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Probably, the easiest way is proposed by [Hans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/928528/hans23).

You may also wan to take a look at Tim Bradshaw's [Conduit packages](http://www.tfeb.org/lisp/hax.html#CONDUITS)

Comment: I'll look into 'conduit packages'. Thanks!